# Change the ifindex of netdev

Tags: linux, networking, indexing, kernel, device

I have the following requirement. I want with a kernel module to change the ifindex of a netdev with one of my choice. I know that it acts as a key and cannot be change during runtime. Created interfaces are based on Intel e1000 driver.
In order to achieve the change the following has been thought:

1. unregister_netdev(dev);
2. //Change the dev->ifindex
3. //bring back network device to operational state somehow, tried register_netdev but this results in kernel panic of course

Can you please inform me if this is somehow possible? I am very new to linux kernel drivers.

Thank you!

Comment: What are yu goinfg to do if the number you choose is already in use?  What will you do about the gap in the numbers?  Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: My number will not be in use by another physical ethernet interface since I will use a specific offset plus the subscript of interface, i.e renaming interfaces eth1 and onwards to gbe1 and so on. I do not care so much about the gap, the change will be done just for testing/emulation purposes. It is for SNMP system that uses ifindexes instead of ifnames to fetch info. Do you have any idea on how to tackle the ifindex change to the preferred one? We are talking about 6 to 8 ethernet interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found a trick/way to tackle this issue:

1. create a dummy network namespace
2. use `dev_change_net_namespace(struct net_device *dev, struct net *net, const char  *pat)` to move device to this namespace
3. then use `__dev_change_net_namespace(struct net_device *dev, struct net *net, const char *pat, int new_ifindex)` to move **dev** to **init_net** with the
   desired **new_ifindex**
4. delete dummy network namespace

In my kernel `__dev_change_net_namespace(struct net_device *dev, struct net *net, const char *pat, int new_ifindex)` does not exist but it is not though so hard to be created since it only pickups a new_ifindex in case it is not provided, or checks the provided one if it is currently used inside namespace

Not tested yet, but it will be very soon.